# Failed to create WiFi hotspot in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hot-spot

I can't make a hotspot. I'm trying this for so long. After installing new Ubuntu 16.04 I found this problem. I have installed a driver from [Here](http://onthim.blogspot.in/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html).

[image].

```
partha@partha-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for partha: 
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:bb:65:82  
          inet addr:172.18.215.50  Bcast:172.18.215.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::3466:e0e9:ce7b:a691/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53972 errors:0 dropped:633 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35492 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:47526952 (47.5 MB)  TX bytes:4039591 (4.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:946253 (946.2 KB)  TX bytes:946253 (946.2 KB)

rename3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5a:b6:2a:8d:ad  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:407 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8673 (8.6 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18
```